# How to change the color of Notification's subtext in Andriod O?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

The default color for subtext is Black. Does anyone know how to change it? I Only care about the subtxt, not include content title and content text.
Thanks.

Comment: Sub text is shown next to app name in header of the notification afaik. You may try `setCustomHeadsUpContentView()`.

Comment: @HongfeeMo : Were you able to update notification's subText Color by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

```
CharSequence boldUsernameMessage = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Hi" +"</b> " + "you got a message");
builder.setContentText(boldUsernameMessage);
```

This will make the text bolder by adding the < b> tag. Try this way to make things colourful.